# question about parameter on add line to the context menu

Tags: windows, registry, explorer

I wrote the following lines in windows registry...

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runDOT]
    @="run in DOT environment"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runDOT\command]
    @="\"D:\\T00Ls\\x64\\DOT\\DOT.exe\" \"%1\""
```

that works like a charm!

Through parameter **%1**, any executable file that is selected through the context menu in explorer, is loaded by **DOT.exe**

To load a second file with the same name, but with a different extension, how will be the variable that I should use?

When creating context menu entries in the registry, what variables can be passed to the commands?

rmk.: I found the following doc, but not helped me.

[Extending Shortcut Menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @Compo, either my english is too bad or you really don't understand my doubt!
About the tags, something happened and changed them, but I fixed it.

Comment: This site does not directly provide advice on how to do it; that is general programming. Here, given a [[tag:batch-file]] tag, you would be asking for assistance with a specific issue with your provided batch file code. You have not shown us your batch file code, you haven't mentioned batch files, and other than the fact that batch files can modify the Windows, _(not DOS)_, registry, there's no correlation between them and your task. What you appear to need is somebody to provide you with a modification of your reg file, to insert `-cfg \"%~n1.cfg\"` into your shell command line.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarifications, I will modify my text to suit your orientation.

Comment: The registered command is just a command, not a programming language. You can register a custom program that does the necessary manipulations, and then calls the original `dot.exe` program. The document you found is the correct one.

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes, you are correct, I used the wrong terms, which suggested that! I will fix it! thank you so much!